# Strange Cycles Area Light artifact when using Motion Blur in animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, motion-blur

I've discovered a strange Cycles artifact when using Area Lights in combination with Motion Blur in an animation.

Per the attached screenshot, two astronauts are at the windows of a moving spacecraft. There are four Area Lights inside the spacecraft between the astronauts and windows acting as fill lights for the astronauts. The strange artifact appears when Motion Blur is enabled, causing the Area Lights to appear to be moving at a different velocity from the spacecraft. The result is that the Area Lights themselves become visible, especially the green light at the far left window; in reality it's behind the post between the windows.

Is this a known issue? If yes, any way to fix it short of disabling Motion Blur? Thanks. Blender 3.6, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: I've just tested it with a simple scene, the motion blur does not make the area lights appear from behind the posts. So maybe there is something specific in your scene which creates this effect, hard to tell without your file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I submitted a bug report to the Blender developer's forum: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/110972#issue-101160. Appears it may be a known issue.